# Removing from supreview only if it exist

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am working on an ipad program in my spare time and i have come across a little issue. In my uisplitview, if i click a cell, it loads a picture i have two other cells, each with this code for when clicked

```
[self.icon1 removeFromSuperview];
```

This works fine to remove the picture however. If after i click cell one with the picture...then i click cell 2 (and this remove code is run) it correctly removes the pic. but if i click cell 3...then the program breaks (bad access and it points to the removeFromSuperview). while i think this happens because the icon has already been removed. Is there a function that says basically says "if exist then removefrom superview"?
thank you

```
if (([receivedRainObject isEqualToString:@"Facts"]) && (Track==100)) {
    self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    //     self.tvFacts=[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 150, 700, 500)];
    self.tvFacts.text=@"  Test";

    [tvFacts setEditable:NO];

     UIImage *acheivement1=[UIImage imageNamed:@"saychesse.png"];
    [factBanner1 setImage:acheivement1];

    UIImage *fbIcon= [UIImage imageNamed:@"facebook.png"];
     fbIcon1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    fbIcon1.frame = CGRectMake(580.0, 305.0, 35.0, 35.0);
    fbIcon1.tag=TAG_BUTTON_ONE;
    [fbIcon1 addTarget:self action:@selector(authButtonAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [fbIcon1 setBackgroundImage:fbIcon forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    UIImage *twIcon= [UIImage imageNamed:@"twitter.png"];
    twIcon1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    twIcon1.frame = CGRectMake(530.0, 305.0, 35.0, 35.0);
    [twIcon1 addTarget:self action:@selector(tweetTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [twIcon1 setBackgroundImage:twIcon forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [self.imgClassification removeFromSuperview];
    [self.Image removeFromSuperview];

    [self.lblSel removeFromSuperview];
    [self.tvDescrip removeFromSuperview];
    [self.tvName removeFromSuperview];
    [self.tvDiet removeFromSuperview];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [self.lblPictureAnnotation removeFromSuperview];
    [self.lbllife removeFromSuperview];
    [self.tvGestation removeFromSuperview];

    [self.view addSubview:self.tvFacts];
    [self.view addSubview:factBanner1];
    [self.view addSubview:fbIcon1];
    [self.view addSubview:twIcon1];
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];

}
// Life-Span         
if (([receivedRainObject isEqualToString:@"Life Span"]) && (Track==100)) {
    self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    //     self.lbllife=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 150, 700, 500)];
    self.lbllife.text=@"The";

    [lbllife setEditable:NO];
    [self.factBanner1 removeFromSuperview];
   [self.fbIcon1 removeFromSuperview];
    [self.twIcon1 removeFromSuperview];
     [self.factBanner2 removeFromSuperview];
      [self.fbIcon2 removeFromSuperview];
    [self.twIcon2 removeFromSuperview];
    [self.imgClassification removeFromSuperview];
    [self.Image removeFromSuperview];

    [self.lblSel removeFromSuperview];
    [self.tvDescrip removeFromSuperview];
    [self.tvName removeFromSuperview];
    [self.tvDiet removeFromSuperview];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [self.tvFacts removeFromSuperview];
    [self.lblPictureAnnotation removeFromSuperview];
    [self.tvGestation removeFromSuperview];
     [self.factBanner1 removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view addSubview:self.lbllife];
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];        
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's the subview that's the problem, or is it the root `self` that's being deallocated?

Comment: One, this isn't even remotely related to Xcode. Two, show your code. It's more likely that you have a memory management error and your suspection is incorrect.

Comment: thats more like memory problem. you have a reference to a deallocated object. try enable NSZombie and see

Comment: i added some code. hope it is what you are looking for in the first if it shows where i assign the fb and tw icon if that cell is clicked and it is supposed to be removed when another cell is clicked. but if i click on another cell with that remove from supervuew code a second time. Thats where my error pops up

Comment: which line did it crash? what is the output from console after you enabled NSZombie? (google it if you don't know how to enable it) you can also try static-analysis in Xcode (shift+cmd+b)

Comment: How is the property `self.icon1` defined?

Comment: @mrueg its fbicon sorry

Comment: @xlc     [self.factBanner1 removeFromSuperview];
   [self.fbIcon1 removeFromSuperview];
    [self.twIcon1 removeFromSuperview];
     
these are the lines...it points to the first one but when i comment one out it moves down to the second

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you already removed `self.icon1` from its superview at some point and the `icon1` property is a `weak` reference.

This means that `icon1` is only retained by its superview. So, after you removed it for the first time, it gets deallocated and when you try to use it a second time, you get the error.

The solution: Either change the `icon1` property to a `strong` reference or (better), do `self.icon1 = nil` after `[self.icon1 removeFromSuperview];`.

By the way, this is the kind of bug that the Clang static analyzer (run it with `Product > Analyze`) is usually able to detect.

Comment: Ok, going to try. Thank you

Comment: Would you tell me why setting it to nil works thou? is it that it will not be deallocated?

Comment: It still gets deallocated, but setting it to nil prevents you from calling a method on the deallocated view object. When you set it to `nil`, any call to `[self.icon removeFromSuperview];` becomes equivalent to `[nil removeFromSuperview];`, which simply does nothing.

Comment: Oh, and you might want to set all the other things on which you call `removeFromSuperview` to `nil` as well, to prevent future crashes.